# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Improper close state: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 7 sequenceNumber = 0

Tags: ssl, ftps, apache-mina, ftp-server, apache-ftpserver

I am getting the below error when I tried to connect FTP server which is running in an open shift cluster. I want to upload the file to the FTP server with the below code.

I have referred to the below URL to write the code.

- https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html

Has anyone faced this error and solved it?

**ERROR**

```
    "stack_trace": "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Improper close state: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 7 sequenceNumber = 0
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.closeOutbound(SslHandler.java:496)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.initiateClosure(SslFilter.java:773)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.filterClose(SslFilter.java:704)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:88)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.filterClose(CommonEventFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter.filterClose(ExecutorFilter.java:608)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.filterClose(IoFilterAdapter.java:146)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:88)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.filterClose(CommonEventFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.filterClose(IoFilterAdapter.java:146)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.filterClose(IoFilterAdapter.java:146)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:769)
    at org.apache.mina.core.session.AbstractIoSession.closeNow(AbstractIoSession.java:353)
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandlerAdapter.inputClosed(IoHandlerAdapter.java:102)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:997)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:101)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.inputClosed(CommonEventFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:101)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.logging.MdcInjectionFilter.filter(MdcInjectionFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.util.CommonEventFilter.inputClosed(CommonEventFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:728)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1224)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1213)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

**Spring Boot Java Code**

```
@Configuration
public class FtpServerConfig {
    @Bean
    public FtpServerFactory ftpServerFactory() throws FtpException {
        FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
        ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
        //set server address
        factory.setServerAddress("localhost");
        //set port
        factory.setPort(50001);

        // SSL config
        SslConfigurationFactory ssl = new SslConfigurationFactory();
        ssl.setKeystoreFile(new File("/tmp/tls/keystore.jks"));
        ssl.setKeystorePassword("passward");
        // set the SSL configuration for the listener
        factory.setSslConfiguration(ssl.createSslConfiguration());
        factory.setImplicitSsl(true);


        //set dataconfig factory
        DataConnectionConfigurationFactory dataConnectionConfigFactory = new DataConnectionConfigurationFactory();
        //set active enabled is false then it will go through with passive connection
        dataConnectionConfigFactory.setActiveEnabled(false);
        //set passive ports range
        dataConnectionConfigFactory.setPassivePorts("50000-60100");
        factory.setDataConnectionConfiguration(dataConnectionConfigFactory.createDataConnectionConfiguration());

        // add listener
        serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());
        // add user
        serverFactory.setUserManager(getUserManager());
        return serverFactory;
    }

    private UserManager getUserManager() throws FtpException {
        PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
        UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();

        BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
        user.setName("user");
        user.setPassword("123");

        FileUtil.createNewDirectory(ftpServerDir);
        user.setHomeDirectory("/tmp/my_ftp_server");
        user.setEnabled(true);
        List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new WritePermission());
        authorities.add(new ConcurrentLoginPermission(0, 0));
        authorities.add(new TransferRatePermission(0, 0));
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        userManager.save(user);
        return userManager;
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class FtpServerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private FtpServerFactory ftpServerFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FtpServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        FtpServer ftpServer = ftpServerFactory.createServer();
        ftpServer.start();
    }
}
```